# NpgsqlConnection.Open blocked in Npgsql.ConnectorPool.Allocate() call to Monitor.Enter

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, deadlock, npgsql

.NET 5.6.1 Tasks Parallel Library - based application stopped responding in NpSql.dll 3.1.6 call to *NpgsqlConnection.Open()*.

After further investigation it appeared that 100's of threads servicing particular connection string were waiting on Monitor.Enter signal. The waiting threads' callstacks were identical to this:

```
[GCFrame: 000000cd8922cec8] 
[GCFrame: 000000cd8922d0f0] 
[HelperMethodFrame: 000000cd8922d128] System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
Npgsql.ConnectorPool.Allocate(Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql.NpgsqlTimeout)
Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.OpenInternal()
```

The locks dump pointed to the orphaned lock issue: MonitorHeld value equaled to 1 owner + 546 waiters (1+546*2=1093), with the lock owner thread dead (Thread is  0)

```
Index     SyncBlock      MonitorHeld    Owning  Thread    Info       Owner
220427  000000d26dd7b028   1093           1       0        XXX   Npgsql.ConnectorPool
```

There were no exceptions generated from inside the unsafe block of code in *ConnectorPool.Allocate()* that would help explaining the orphaned lock.

There was was no reason to believe *our* code caused the thread die prematurely either: nowhere in the application did we explicitly call *Thread.Abort()*.

At this point we ran out of ideas. 
Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Seems like this issue is related: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1251

Comment: Yes they are related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

1. The bug report was [submitted](http://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1251) to npsql by a member of our team.
2. After more thorough search through our logs we found single instance of NullReferenceException coming from within ConnectorPool.Allocate() in NpSql dll  version 3.1.6 due to race condition. Looking at [ConnectorPool.cs](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/master/src/Npgsql/PoolManager.cs) in current NpSql repo this particular issue had been fixed by converting static _pruningTimer to the instance-based field since version 3.1.7.

Conclusion: An upgrade from NpSql 3.1.6 to 3.1.7 resolved the deadlock in ConnectorPool.Allocate().